# What is difference between types int** and int[][]?

Tags: c++

If the following assignment is valid:

```
int a[2] = {1,2};
int* b = a;
```

then what is wrong with this:

```
int a[2][2]={1,2,3,4};
int** b = a;
```

C++ gives an error that it can't convert `int[][]` to `int**`. What is difference between the two types if `int[]` is the same as `int*`?

Comment: Take a look at all the answers, you'll learn a lot! (But take your time also.;))

Comment: [related FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Take it easy. It is only a compiler error. Arrays are pretty tricky. Here is the *rule*:

> The value of a variable of type array **decays** to the **address of element zero** of this array

Your first snippet looks like:

```
int a[2] = {1,2};
```

So according to the rule if `a` is in the right hand side of a assignment then it decays to address of the element zero and that is why it has type `int *`. This brings you to

```
int *b = a;
```

In the second snippet what you really have is an array of arrays. (By the way, to make it explicit I've changed your code a bit.)

```
int a[2][2]={{1,2},{3,4}};
```

This time `a` will decay to the pointer to an *array of two integers*! So if you would want to assign `a` to something, you would need this something to have the same type.

```
int (*b)[2] = a; //Huh!
```

(This syntax maybe a bit stunning to you, but just think for a moment that we have written `int *b[2];` Got the point? `b` would be an array of pointers to integers! Not really what we wanted...)

You could stop reading here, but you could also move on, because I have not told you all the truth. The *rule* I mentioned has three exceptions...

The value of the array will **not** decay to the address of the element zero **if**

1. array is operand of `sizeof`
2. array is operand of `&`
3. array is a literal string initializer for a character array

Let's explain these exceptions in more detail and with examples:

```
int a[2];

int *pi = a ; /* the same as pi = &a[0]; */

printf("%d\n", sizeof(a)); /* size of the array, not of a pointer is printed! */

int (*pi2)[2] = &a; /* address of the array itself is taken (not the address of a pointer) */
```

And finally

```
char a[] = "Hello world ";
```

Here not a pointer to "Hello world" is copied, but the whole string is copied and a points to this copy.

There is *really* a lot of information and it is really difficult to understand everything at once, so take your time. I recommend you to read K&R on this topic and afterwards [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131774298) excellent book.

Comment: +1, calming the developer when debugging in C++ is usually the first step. :D

Comment: It's not a warning, it's a fundamental incompatibility in the binary layout of the two types.

Comment: @ChrisLutz Thank you, just my bad English.

Comment: OP note that while `b` is valid and it'll compile, in order to use it to access the elements of `a` you're going to need to specify the bounds, ie. `int (*b)[2] = a;`.

Comment: @AusCBloke There is so much to say about it that for a beginner is just way tooo much :(

Comment: Yeah true. @bhuwansahni: you should take a read of K&R. Anyway +1.

Comment: You say "`a` is address of the element zero and has type `int *`", but `int a[]` is not the same as `int *a`. See http://cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10/

Comment: @TimothyJones Yes.. I'd need to improve it. What I really want to say is that `a` decay to ... if `a` is in the right side of the assignment.

Comment: I would say something like "if you assign an `int[]` to an `int*` the compiler does the conversion for you" (you illustrate this in your example later in your answer). I'm not a fan of the use of "decay", as there are actually more steps to access an `int*` than there are to access an `int[]`.

Comment: @TimothyJones I'm using decay, because it's kind of terminology that is used in books. The second point you make is also very important. But this is a material for another question or so.

Comment: Good answer (way too many people misunderstand this).  Suggested reading: section 6 of the [comp.lang.d FAQ](http://c-faq.com).

Comment: +1 I've learned that there is still another situation when an array is not converted to a pointer: when using an array to initialize a reference to the array.Is it right?

Comment: @zyc you mean this one `int (*pi2)[2] = &a;`? If so, call it pointer in order not to mix it with C++ references.

Comment: Actually I mean this: `void foo(int (&arr)[10]){/*...*/}`. In this function the parameter is a reference to an array of 10 ints.And the array does not decay to a pointer points to this array.

Comment: I this not c++? In c++ you hqve to turn it around and ask "when *does* the array decay?". It does only if needes in c++! *Much* less often than in c, which your answer applies to.

Comment: @zyc Ah, you are right, I haven't taken a look at this example here.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb *"when does the array decay?"* At the beginning I've said that it always decays, however *later* I added three exceptions. zyc gaved me another one. Are there something else that should be mentioned?

Comment: @KeithThompson Kudos for supplying an amazing link!

Answer (score 7):

This is something that comes up a lot, so I will attempt to explain it as clearly as I can.

When you make an array, it stores the elements contiguously in memory, so:

```
int arr[2] = { 1, 2 };
```

Translates to:

```
arr:
+---+---+
| 1 | 2 |
+---+---+
```

A pointer points to an object in memory, and when dereferenced, via unary `*` or via `[]`, it accesses that contiguous memory. So after

```
int *ptr = arr;
```

`ptr` (or `&ptr[0]` if you like) points to the box `1` is in, and `ptr + 1` (or `&ptr[1]`) points to the box `2` is in. This makes sense.

But if arrays are contiguous in memory, arrays of arrays are contiguous in memory. So:

```
int arr[2][2] = {{ 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }};
```

Looks in memory like this:

```
arr:
+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
+---+---+---+---+
```

Which looks a lot like our flat array.

Now, let's consider how a pointer to a pointer to an `int` would be laid out in memory:

```
ptr:
+-------+-------+
| &sub1 | &sub2 |
+-------+-------+

sub1:
+---+---+
| 1 | 2 |
+---+---+

sub2:
+---+---+
| 3 | 4 |
+---+---+
```

`ptr` (or `&ptr[0]`) points to `sub1`, and `ptr + 1` (or `&ptr[1]`) points to `sub2`. `sub1` and `sub2` have no actual relation to each other, and can be anywhere in memory, but because it's a pointer *to a pointer*, the double-dereference of a 2D array is preserved, even though the memory structure is not compatible.

Arrays of type `T` decay to pointers to type `T`, but arrays of arrays of type `T` do not decay to pointers to pointers to type `T`, they decay to pointers to arrays of type `T`. So when our 2D `arr` decays to a pointer, it is not a pointer to a pointer to an `int`, but a pointer to an `int [2]`. The full name of this type is `int (*)[2]`, and to make your line of code work you'd want to use

```
int (*ptr)[2] = arr;
```

Which is the correct type. `ptr` expects to point to a contiguous array of memory, like `arr` does - `ptr` (or `&ptr[0]`) points to `arr` and `ptr + 1` (or `&ptr[1]`) points to `&arr[1]`. `ptr[0]` points to the box that holds `1`, and `ptr[1]` points to the box that holds `3`, so `ptr[0][0]` yields 1, `ptr[0][1]` yields 2, and so on.

Why do you need to know this? 2D pointers seem more complicated than they're worth - if you were using `malloc` you'd have to call `malloc` repeatedly in a loop, and do the same for `free`. OR, you could use some evil* trickery to make a flat, 1-dimensional allocation of memory *act* like a 2D array:

```
// x and y are the first and second dimensions of your array
// so it would be declared T arr[x][y] if x and y were static

int (*arr)[y] = malloc(x * y * sizeof(arr[0][0]));
if(!arr) /* error */;
```

Now `arr` points to a contiguous block of arrays of size `y` of `int` objects. Since the object it points to is an array, we don't need the double-pointer-indirection of `int **` objects, and when you're done, you can free it with one call:

```
free(arr);
```

Compare this to a version using `int **`:

```
int **arr = malloc(x * sizeof(*arr));
if(!arr) /* error */;
for(size_t ii = 0; ii < x; ii++)
  {
    arr[ii] = malloc(y * sizeof(**arr));
    if(!arr[ii])
      {
        free(arr[ii]);
        free(arr);
      }
  }
// do work
for(size_t ii = 0; ii < x; ii++)
    free(arr[ii]);
free(arr);
```

The above code has a memory leak. See if you can find it. (Or just use the version with those seemingly tricky pointers-to-arrays.)

Comment: As a side note, `int (*ptr)[2]` may look confusing, and rightly so. The command-line (and now web-based) tool [cdecl](http://cdecl.org) can help you decode C declarations into plain English.

Answer (score 4):

The famous **decay convention**: an array is treated as a pointer that points to the first element of the array.

```
int a[2] = {1,2};
int* b = a; //decay
```

But the decay convention shouldn't be applied more than once to the same object.

```
int a[2][2]={1,2,3,4};
int** b = a; //decay more than once
```

Answer (score 2):

`int[]` isn't the same as `int*`.  `int[]` will *decay* into an `int*` *in certain contexts*.

You probably should read the [comp.lang.c FAQ,](http://www.c-faq.com/index.html) particularly:

- [Q6.2 But I heard that `char a[]` was identical to `char *a`.](http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html)
- [Q6.3 So what is meant by the "equivalence of pointers and arrays" in C?](http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html)

and perhaps the rest of the [Array and Pointers](http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html) section.