# What is the difference between array[ROWS][COLS] and **array

Tags: c

Why aren't these function prototypes equivalent?

```
void print_matrix(char *name, int SX, int SY, int m[SX][SY])

void print_matrix(char *name, int SX, int SY, int **m)
```

Comment: Hey guys, let's not pick on @richard too much - he's probably not doing the downvoting.  I myself had forgotten that C has different rules for local variables as it does for parameter types.  There's also the issue of VLAs.  You can't expect richard to appreciate all these subtleties.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is difference between types int** and int\[\]\[\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395255/what-is-difference-between-types-int-and-int)

Comment: Sorry, I thought at first that you had changed so much about this question that you wanted it rolled back to the original. I've removed the comments that were made obsolete, but you have a good answer here to the question as asked, so it all worked out. In the future, rather than making a dramatic change to a question that totally alters its meaning, simply leave it be and ask a new question on the new topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though the two function arguments can be *consumed* in the same way, namely via `m[i][j]`, they're quite different:

- `int m[M][N]` is an array of `M` arrays of `N` ints.
- `int **m` is a pointer to a pointer to an int.

You cannot pass arrays as function arguments, so an "array of `K` elements of type `T`" decays to a "poin­ter-to-`T`", pointing to the first element of the array. Thus it is permissible and equivalent to write the first form as `int m[][N]` in a function argument, since the value `M` is lost. However, the value `N` is *not* lost; it is part of the type!

So the following are admissible/erroneous for the first form:

```
void f(int arr[M][N]);

int a[M][N];
int b[2*M][N];
int c[M][N + 1];

f(a);   // OK
f(b);   // OK; slowest extent is forgotten in the decay
//f(c); // Error! 'c' is not an array of {array of N ints}.
```

For the second form, the meaning is rather different:

```
void g(int **p);

int a;
int * pa = &a;

g(&pa);          // fine, pointer to 'pa'

int arr[M][N];

// g(arr);  // Error, makes no sense
```

The expression `arr` designates the pointer to the first element of an array of arrays of `N` integers, i.e. its type is `int (*)[N]`. Dereferencing it gives an array of `N` integers, and *not* a pointer to an integer.

There is no way to convert the expression `arr` into a pointer to a pointer: If you said,

```
int ** fool = (int**)arr;
```

then `*fool` would point to the first element of the first array (`arr[0]`), and *not to an `int` pointer*. So you cannot dereference the value further, because the value *is not a pointer*.

The only *correct* way to pass a two-dimensional array as a double pointer is to construct an intermediate helper array:

```
int * helper[M];   // array of pointers

for (size_t i = 0; i != M; ++i)
{
    helper[i] = arr[i]; // implicit decay
}

g(helper);  // or "g(&helper[0])"
```